# Struggling with Selenium as a new backend developer

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to web scraping and am trying to build an algorithm to pull all of the information from my school's course catalog. What I have so far is:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
import os 
import time
from selenium.common import exceptions  


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url=.("https://webapps.lsa.umich.edu/CrsMaint/Public/CB_PublicBulletin.aspx?crselevel=ug/robots.txt")
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*.[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlPage"]/option[4]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlTerm"]/option[1]').click() 

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSubject"]/option[8]').click() 

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch"]').click()
```

I've had much more but keep running into Selenium errors about not being able to locate the information when it is correct. Can anyone get me on the right track? Trying to pull all of the information!

Cheers

Comment: if the DOM updates via javascript, you'll want to use WebDriverWaits after you click: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/

Comment: What would your desired out be?

Comment: I want to pull every course and their descriptions into my terminal/output. This is obviously bear bone where it only selects one subject and doesn't pull the table yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played around with your code and used it as a base for something a bit more what you'd expect.

Try this:

```
import textwrap

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://webapps.lsa.umich.edu/CrsMaint/Public/CB_PublicBulletin.aspx")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlPage"]/option[4]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlTerm"]/option[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSubject"]/option[8]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch"]').click()

tables = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser").find_all("td", {"valign": "top"})


def wrapper(text: str, width: int = 120) -> str:
    return "\n".join(textwrap.wrap(text, width=width)) + "\n"


for table in tables:
    try:
        title = table.find("b").getText(strip=True)
        course_info = " ".join(table.find("i").text.split())
        desc = table.find("p").getText(strip=True)
        urls = [f"{a.text.strip()} - {a['href']}" for a in table.find_all("a")]
        print(title)
        print(wrapper(course_info))
        print(wrapper(desc))
        print("\n".join(urls) if urls else "No URL's found.")
        print("-" * 120)
    except AttributeError:
        continue

driver.close()
```

In my terminal the output (it's just a small part of it, as there's lots) looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is amazing help. Now I'm iterating through the xpaths and it works perfectly.